# Page overflowing beyond footer

Tags: html, css

For whatever reason, on this page, whenever I zoom out the the footer starts moving up and page page overflows beyond i. I've tried setting a min-height:100vh to my form element, which did fix the the problem, however as you can imagine, my form became a lot longer.

I've also tried to add a margin-bottom:0 to the last child element of my body but that also did not fix the issue. For whatever reason this only happens on certain pages I've made whilst the others are fine.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  line-height: 1.5;
}


/* "Retrieved from stackoverflow to fix a spill issue with our page: " */

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}


/* Nav Bar CSS beginning*/

.Navigation-Bar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15)
}

.logo {
  width: 200px;
  height: 80px;
  padding: 1.5vw 7vw;
  padding-top: 4px;
}


/* Turns the ul vertically instead of horizantally */

ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 1vw 7vw;
}


/* This deals with the vertical spacing  of the li on the nav bar */

nav ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  position: relative;
  /* text-decoration: none; */
  color: #000;
}


/* This deals with the easeing in/out of the li underline */

nav ul li a::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: -5px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #BC3838;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

nav ul li a:hover::before {
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scaleX(1);
}


/* End:This deals with the easeing in/out of the li underline */


/* li a CSS adds spacing to the li and removes the underlining. Changes the color to black and other small formating */

li a {
  margin-left: 80px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500px;
  color: black;
}

li a:hover {
  color: maroon;
}


/* Hamburger menu begins */

.toggle-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2.5rem;
  right: 1rem;
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 30px;
  height: 21px;
}

.toggle-button .bar {
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .toggle-button {
    display: flex;
  }
  .navbar-links {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
}


/* Hamburger menu ends */


/* Nav Bar CSS End*/

body {
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #ffffff 50%, #BC3838 50%);
}

form {
  height: 460px;
  width: 600px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin: 145px 0px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  padding: 50px 35px;
}

form * {
  font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}

form h3 {
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 42px;
  text-align: center;
}

label {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

input {
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.07);
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

 ::placeholder {
  color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
}

button {
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #080710;
  padding: 15px 0;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 600;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

form {
  background: #BC3838;
}

.Forgot {
  font-size: 15px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.login-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-right: 290px;
}

.noaccount {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  left: 68%;
  top: 17%;
  font-size: 45px;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}

.subtext2 {
  position: relative;
  left: 62%;
  top: 20%;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-size: 19px;
  color: white;
}

.registerbutton {
  position: relative;
  left: 65%;
  top: 24%;
}

.fulllogo {
  position: relative;
  top: 0%;
  left: 13%;
}

.halflogo {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin-left: 10.3px;
  width: 100px;
}

footer {
  padding: 5vw;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

footer .footer-elements {
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

footer h9 {
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

footer li {
  list-style: none;
  color: grey;
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 15px;
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<nav class="Navigation-Bar">
  <div>
    <a href="../Home Page/Home Page.html"><img class="logo" src="../Home Page/UOLOGO3.png"></a>
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="toggle-button">
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
  </a>
  <div class="navbar-links">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="../Home Page/Home Page.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="../courses page/CoursePageV2.html">Courses</a>
        <li><a href="../FAQ/FAQ Attempt 3.html">FAQ</a></li>
        <li><a href="../Contact Page1/contactpage0.html">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="../Register Page/login.html" id="login/register">Login/Register</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<img class="halflogo" src="Picture1.png" />

<div class="Register">
  <div class="noaccount">Register</div>
  <div class="subtext2">Don't have an account? Register here!</div>
  <a href="../Register Page/register page Final.html" class="registerbutton"><button style="background-color: white; padding: 10px; font-size: 15px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; width: 20%;">Register an account</button></a>
</div>
<div class="login-container">
  <form class="Login">
    <h3>Login</h3>
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Email or Phone" id="username" />
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password" />
    <div class="Forgot"><a href="../Register Page/forgotpassword.html">Forgot your password?</a></div>
    <button>Log In</button>
  </form>
</div>

<section class="footer">
  <footer>
    <div class="footer-elements">
      <h9>Our Products</h9>
      <li>Math</li>
      <li>Enligh</li>
      <li>Coding</li>
      <li>Knitting</li>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h9>Customer Support</h9>
      <li>We provide support from 9:00 a.m. to midnight EST, seven days a week.</li>
      <h9>Phone</h9>
      <li>1-800-800-8000</li>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h9>Acces a course</h9>
      <li>Click here to login!</li>
      <li>Click here to register!</li>
      <li>Forgot your password?</li>
    </div>
  </footer>
</section>
```

Comment: I suggest running your markup through a validator (or using a good editor). You have several problems: 1) List items must be children of a list. The can't be arbitrarily sprinkled around your document. 2) Anchors and buttons have different, distinct purposes. They should never be nested. 3) There's no `h9` element in HTML.

Comment: You've overcomplicated things with fixed sizes, translation, and other heavy-handed styling. I don't have a good answer because these things all combine to create a challenging layout situation. That, along with the issues I mentioned earlier, make a bit of a mess. I suggest starting fresh and only bringing in the styles you actually need. This doesn't need to be so complicated.

Comment: Thank you for the tips. This is a collaborative work so I'm trying to make update the original page as I didn't create it. Makes for difficult editing . I look over your notes and make the necessary adjustments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add flex or grid container on body

```
body{
display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  /* background-color: #fff; */
  font-size: 1.1em;
  line-height: 1.5;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}


/* "Retrieved from stackoverflow to fix a spill issue with our page: " */

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}


/* Nav Bar CSS beginning*/

.Navigation-Bar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15)
}

.logo {
  width: 200px;
  height: 80px;
  padding: 1.5vw 7vw;
  padding-top: 4px;
}


/* Turns the ul vertically instead of horizantally */

ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 1vw 7vw;
}


/* This deals with the vertical spacing  of the li on the nav bar */

nav ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  position: relative;
  /* text-decoration: none; */
  color: #000;
}


/* This deals with the easeing in/out of the li underline */

nav ul li a::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: -5px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #BC3838;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}


/*  */

nav ul li a:hover::before {
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scaleX(1);
}


/* End:This deals with the easeing in/out of the li underline */


/* li a CSS adds spacing to the li and removes the underlining. Changes the color to black and other small formating */

li a {
  margin-left: 80px;
  /* This changes the spacing between the li*/
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500px;
  color: black;
}

li a:hover {
  color: maroon;
  /* When hovering over a list element in the nav bar this highlight the element maroon */
}


/* Hamburger menu begins */

.toggle-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2.5rem;
  right: 1rem;
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 30px;
  height: 21px;
}

.toggle-button .bar {
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .toggle-button {
    display: flex;
  }
  .navbar-links {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
}


/* Hamburger menu ends */


/* Nav Bar CSS End*/

body {
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #ffffff 50%, #BC3838 50%);
}


/* *,
    *:before,
    *:after {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    } */


/* body {
    background-color: #080710;
    overflow: hidden;
    } */

form {
  height: 460px;
  width: 600px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin: 145px 0px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  /* box-shadow: 0 0 40px rgba(8, 7, 16, 0.6); */
  padding: 50px 35px;
}

form * {
  font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}

form h3 {
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 42px;
  text-align: center;
}

label {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

input {
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.07);
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

 ::placeholder {
  color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
}

button {
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #080710;
  padding: 15px 0;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 600;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

form {
  background: #BC3838;
}

.Forgot {
  font-size: 15px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.login-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-right: 290px;
}

.noaccount {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  left: 68%;
  top: 17%;
  font-size: 45px;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}

.subtext2 {
  position: relative;
  left: 62%;
  top: 20%;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-size: 19px;
  color: white;
}

.registerbutton {
  position: relative;
  left: 65%;
  top: 24%;
}

.fulllogo {
  position: relative;
  top: 0%;
  left: 13%;
}

.halflogo {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin-left: 10.3px;
  width: 100px;
}

footer {
  padding: 5vw;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

footer .footer-elements {
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

footer h9 {
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

footer li {
  list-style: none;
  color: grey;
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 15px;
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<nav class="Navigation-Bar">
  <div>
    <a href="../Home Page/Home Page.html"><img class="logo" src="../Home Page/UOLOGO3.png"></a>
  </div>
  
  <a href="#" class="toggle-button">
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
  </a>
  
  <div class="navbar-links">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="../Home Page/Home Page.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="../courses page/CoursePageV2.html">Courses</a>
        <li><a href="../FAQ/FAQ Attempt 3.html">FAQ</a></li>
        <li><a href="../Contact Page1/contactpage0.html">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="../Register Page/login.html" id="login/register">Login/Register</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<img class="halflogo" src="Picture1.png" />

<div class="Register">
  <div class="noaccount">Register</div>
  <div class="subtext2">Don't have an account? Register here!</div>
  <a href="../Register Page/register page Final.html" class="registerbutton"><button style="background-color: white; padding: 10px; font-size: 15px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; width: 20%;">Register an account</button></a>
</div>

<div class="login-container">
  <form class="Login">
    <h3>Login</h3>
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Email or Phone" id="username" />
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password" />
    <div class="Forgot"><a href="../Register Page/forgotpassword.html">Forgot your password?</a></div>
    <button>Log In</button>
  </form>
</div>

<section class="footer">
  <footer>
    <div class="footer-elements">
      <h9>Our Products</h9>
      <li>Math</li>
      <li>Enligh</li>
      <li>Coding</li>
      <li>Knitting</li>
    </div>
    
    <div>
    
      <h9>Customer Support</h9>
      <li>We provide support from 9:00 a.m. to midnight EST, seven days a week.</li>
      <h9>Phone</h9>
      <li>1-800-800-8000</li>
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <h9>Acces a course</h9>
      <li>Click here to login!</li>
      <li>Click here to register!</li>
      <li>Forgot your password?</li>
    </div>
  </footer>
</section>
```